# Stripe billing Subscription not charging the "subsequent charges" after initial successful Payment

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, recurring-billing

I have followed [this](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment) documentation to implement the Stripe Recurring Payments, which is working fine for both non-3d-Secure card and 3d-Secure enabled cards. For initial payments i get the 3d-Secure Payment authentication Modal from Stripe to authenticate payments using 3D-Secure Test cards.

The subscription is created along with invoices that Stripe generates for me. Everything's seems to be OK, BUT for 3D-Secure Enabled (Stripe Testing Cards) the First Payment goes through successfully but the subsequent payments which i have set interval of 1Day (for testing) are "Failed" by Stripe. From what i understand Stripe requires Customer's Authentication again to continue the Subscription.

---

In [this](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#recurring-charges) they said

> When 3D Secure is encountered, configure your billing settings to send
>   a hosted link to your customer to complete the flow.

That's completely OK, But why they even require the authentication step again if the first payment is succeeded and the subscription is started? I have gone through all the related Docs but found nothing to prevent that.

What if Customer does not check his/her email to come back to my Application to authenticate the payments?
OR

Is there anything wrong with the code? By that i mean that Stripe should have saved the Payment Method i.e. Card Number so it does not require the Customer Authentication on subsequent charges every time the new billing cycle start(monthly/biannually).

I have searched on internet and found and answer saying

> You are using stripe.createToken which does not support 3ds
>   authentication. You need to migrate your client side code to
>   stripe.createPaymentMethod which does support it

Is that it? Any response is appreciated

**My Payment.js**

```
// set your stripe publishable key
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_key');
var elements = stripe.elements();
var style = {
    base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        lineHeight: '18px',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
            color: '#aab7c4'
        }
    },
    invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
};

var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    style: style
});
cardNumber.mount('#cardNumber');
var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
    style: style
});
cardExpiry.mount('#cardExpiry');
var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
    style: style
});
cardCvc.mount('#cardCVC');

var cardholderName = $('#custName').val();
var amount = $('#amount').val();

var cardButton = document.getElementById('makePayment');
cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
     // alert();
    ev.preventDefault();




    stripe.createToken(cardNumber).then(function(result) {

    if (result.error) {


    } else {
      //$body.addClass("loading");
      fetch('process.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            token_id: result.token.id          
            })
      }).then(function(result) {


        // Handle server response (see Step 3)
        result.json().then(function(json) {
          handleServerResponse(json);
          //alert();
        })
      });
    }
  });
});
function handleServerResponse(response) {
            if (response.error) {
                // Show error from server on payment form
            } else if (response.requires_action) {
                // Use Stripe.js to handle required card action
                var action = response.next_action;
                if (action && action.type == 'redirect_to_url') {
                    window.location = action.redirect_to_url.url;
                }

                handleAction(response);

            } else {
                console.log("3D" + response);
            }
}

        function handleAction(response) {
           var paymentIntentSecret = response.payment_intent_client_secret;
            stripe.handleCardPayment(paymentIntentSecret).then(function(result) {
              if (result.error) {
                // Display error.message in your UI.
              } else {
                // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
                alert('Payment succeeded!');
              }
});

}
```

**Process.php**

```
<?php 

require_once('stripe-php/init.php');   
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_key');

$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
 //print_r($json_obj->token_id);die;

  //$intent = null;
try {
    if (isset($json_obj->token_id)) {
     //Create Customer   
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    "email" => "test@gmail.com",
    "name" => "Haroon",  
    "source" => $json_obj->token_id,
]);
    //create product
    $product = \Stripe\Product::create([
    'name' => 'Water',
    'type' => 'service',
]);
    //create a plan
    $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create([
      'product' => $product->id,
      'nickname' => 'Water',
      'interval' => 'day',
      'currency' => 'eur',
      'amount' => 1200.00,
    ]);   

    //add subscription to stripe
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([

        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'items' => [[
        "plan" => $plan->id],],
        'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
]);    
}

      $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($subscription->latest_invoice->payment_intent->id);

      $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subscription->id);
    //   $intent->confirm();
    // }
    generatePaymentResponse($intent,$subscription);
  }catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
    # Display error on client
    echo json_encode([
      'error' => $e->getMessage()
    ]);
  }  

   function generatePaymentResponse($intent,$subscription) {
    if ($intent->status == 'requires_action' && $subscription->status == 'incomplete' &&
        $intent->next_action->type == 'use_stripe_sdk' ) {
        # Tell the client to handle the action

        echo json_encode([
            'requires_action' => true,
            'payment_intent_client_secret' => $intent->client_secret
        ]);
    } else if ($intent->status == 'succeeded' && $subscription->status == 'active') {

        # The payment didn’t need any additional actions and completed!
        # Handle post-payment fulfillment
        echo json_encode([
            'success' => true
        ]);
    } else if ($intent->status == 'requires_payment_method' && $subscription->status == 'incomplete') {
        echo "Subscription failed";

    } else {
        # Invalid status
        http_response_code(500);
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid PaymentIntent status']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with stripe.createPaymentMethod() but i get error saying "error":"This customer has no attached payment source". means \Stripe\Customer::create is not getting its required "source" parameter which was supplied by token_id.

Comment: If you're using the "3DS" test cards, those will always require authentication because they're not set up to test for SCA exemptions. Can you try the Regulatory test cards at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/testing#regulatory-cards and see if those get you what you're looking for?

Comment: My implementation basically covers both the non-3DS cards and 3DS cards. So its our requirement to test on with both types of cards.As i mentioned in question that non-3DS cards payments are charged without any issue

Comment: @taintedzodiac anyways i will give it a try using regulatory cards as you mentioned

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing this for already exist card then i have done this just before some day .  Refer this document https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure .

This  suggest that you need to create paymentIntent and need to confirm this payment intent . and also in 3ds there are test card 4242 4242 4242 4242 This card does not require any authentication for 3ds .  Giving below link for test cards

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure/web#three-ds-cards

Comment: The problem with the `4242` card is that it will not test SCA regulations at all (it never asks for authentication because it does not support it). The cards for testing SCA are found at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/testing#regulatory-cards

You should also not use the "3DS" test cards for testing SCA, because they all do not support SCA's exemptions for recurring payments (or any other exemptions).